# http security config for tls and Oauth2 in the same method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

I want to make a config file to configure TLS and Oauth2 in my SecureConfig.java

The tls config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
}
```

The Oauth2.0 config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .requiresChannel()
            .anyRequest()
            .requiresSecure();
}
```

What is the better way to use these two in the same config file and method? Does  the and() work fine?

Like that:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER).and()
            .requiresChannel()
            .anyRequest()
            .requiresSecure();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue with your two filter chain approach (Regardless of what your configure inside the methods**

- Spring security is a chain of filters see [Filters in Spring Security Filter Chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480102/how-spring-security-filter-chain-works)
- By implementing `configure(HttpSecurity http)` twice, you have created `two spring-security-filter-chain`s.
- Since you are not providing `http.requestMatcher(...)`, both chains are applicable to every url. And it is a problem for spring security as it will only apply one filter chain to a particular request. So if you try to start up your app, it will fail to start with an error
- You can make your app start by defining an `@Order` annotation so spring security chooses the one with the lower number applicable for a url. But since both chains are applicable to every url as per your config, the filter chain with lower `@Order` overrides the filter chain with higher `@Order` making it useless

**Solution**

- Use one class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` so you have one security filter chain

**Channel Security vs Authentication vs Authorisation**

- Security is mainly 4 aspects. Authentication, Authorisation, Integrity and Confidentiality. [Rest API under https security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62611562/rest-api-under-https-security/62616438#62616438)
- What you have in the filter is about authentication. You may have also defined some urls need some roles which is Authorisation. So that config was about those 2 aspects
- By `requiresSecure()` you are addressing `Confidentiality`. i.e If you use `requiresSecure()` without the first one, you know you are not talking to some middle man but you won't know who you are talking to because that is what the purpose of authentication.
- Since they are complimentary  security aspects, They can be combined together and spring will create one filter chain where the first filter ensures you are first talking over https by placing `ChannelProcessingFilter` as the first barrier